# Cannot run program (java) in (directory "."); file name or extension is too long

Tags: command-line-arguments, java-11, eclipse-classpath, pathtoolongexception

I'm encountering an issue in a Java application run job configuration in Eclipse, where I receive a "cannot run program, the path is too long" exception. I suspect it's related to the extensive list of JAR files in my classpath. Despite trying various solutions, including shortening the command line option in IntelliJ, I still face challenges. In IntelliJ, the error changes to "Process Exited with error code 1." I reduce the classpath also, but still I am getting same issue. Any suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

1.Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\sai\Java\jdk11.0.17_B\bin\java" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error-206, The filename or extension is too long
 at java.base/java.lang. ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1120)
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
 at java.baze/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:592)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Javal3Commandlauncher.exec (Javal3CommandLauncher.java:61)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch (DefaultExecutor.java:279)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:336)
 at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
 at org.apachy.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:153)
Caused by: Java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.base/lava.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:492)
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Frocess Impl.java:153)
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder, start (ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
... 17 more
```

2.Run Configuration:

```
Name : TestDemo 
Project : Demo 
Main Class : com.demo.RunJob 
Program Arguments: -p "testfile.txt" -r 
VM Arguments: -Xmx256M -Xms256M 
-Ddemo.appkey=none 
Runtime JRE: Java 11
```

Comment: You should copy the exact error message you received. Typos can not happen when you copy and paste error messages, so whatever you did, it was not copying the exact error message. If you suspect that the classpath is too long, try to provide it via CLASSPATH environment variable instead of command line argument. As a side note, this `DefaultExecutor` looks like yet another superfluous Apache wrapper around an [existing functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: @Holger I have checked my classpath has so many jars which is throwing exception. My classpath character count is more than 52k, all Jar files are required for my project and it has multiple modules, one will depends on another module. So, can anyone give me some suggestions to handle this issue. Note : I am using intellij now.

Comment: I already told you. Provide a `CLASSPATH` environment variable to the subprocess and remove it from the command line.